# Unable to access xsl file from jar file (Mule)

Tags: java, file, xslt, jar, mule

I have been facing trouble accessing an xsl file located inside a folder in jar file.  I need to get this working in mule-config file.

As given below I need to access an XSL file from a filder inside a jar file from an  xslt transformer.
But it gives out error IOException

```
<mule-xml:xslt-transformer name="rateConverter"     
    xsl-file="classpath:\xslt\ratechanger.xsl">
</mule-xml:xslt-transformer>

the jar structure is 

ccyutil.jar
  |_ xslt
    |_ ratechanger.xsl
```

Error while starting the application is  :

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Unable to load resource classpath:\xslt\ratechanger.xsl
    at org.mule.util.IOUtils.getResourceAsString(IOUtils.java:54)
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer.initialise(XsltTransformer.java:135)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.initialise(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:94)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

2013-05-01 11:23:19,489 ERROR [main] mule.MuleServer (MuleServer.java:474) - 
********************************************************************************
* A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:                     *
* Unable to load resource classpath:\xslt\ratechanger.xsl             *
* (java.io.IOException)                                                        *
*                                                                              *
* The error is fatal, the system will shutdown                                 *
```

It works fine if the xsl file is available in the jar directly instead of a folder.

```
  ccyutil.jar
  |_ ratechanger.xsl
```

*Note: This is not a duplicate question related to accessing files form jar files. I have gone through most of the existing questions but couldn't find a solution.*

Comment: *"I have gone through all those existing questions"*  That's an astonishing claim.  Link to the top 5.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I could see most of the solutions are to get it working in a class file. But I need to get this working in mule-config file.

Comment: 1. the docs need a sign on. what do the docs say? 2. Maybe they have feedback link there you can try?

Comment: You cannot put the file outside jar to test? where is the config file in the relative file path to ccyutil.jar

Comment: The files are working fine when I place them in the resources folder of my project. But problem is accesing them from jar file.  In the jar also I can get the file if it is directly inside the jar file instead of a folder inside a jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it the following way. Its working.

```
  <mule-xml:xslt-transformer name="rateConverter"     
          xsl-file="xslt/ratechanger.xsl">
  </mule-xml:xslt-transformer>
```